# Probability of random variable being lesser than the other

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, measure-concentration

Say there are two *independent* random variables, $X$ and $Y$, and we have samples $\{x_1,\dots x_n\},\{y_1,\dots y_n\}$. I am interested in bounding the probability of the event $C = \mathbb{1}_{X<Y}$, namely bounding  $\mathbb{P}(C)=\mathbb{E}(C) $.

I know that I can define $c_i=\mathbb{1}_{x_i<y_i}$,  and use Chernoff bound in the standard fashion to estimate 
$$\mathbb{P}\bigg(\hat C\in(\mathbb{E}(C)-\epsilon,\mathbb{E}(C)+\epsilon)\bigg) \geq 1-\delta $$

However, doing so means completely ignoring the fact that $X$ and $Y$ are independent, hence seems wrong.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

---

This is what I have done so far, based a partial answer by @passerby51's:

First, we define the U-statistic:
$$
U := \frac1{n^2} \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n 1\{X_j < Y_i\}
$$
Now, we would really like to follow Example 2.10 [from here](http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~mjwain/stat210b/Chap2_TailBounds_Jan22_2015.pdf), with $g(X_i,Y_j)=1_{X_i<Y_j}$. Unfortunately, $1_{X_i<Y_j}$ is not symmetric (as needed from the proof of the cited example). One lead as hinted by @passerby51, is to decompose $U$ into two terms, i.e.
$$
U := \frac1{n^2}\underbrace{\sum_{k=1}^n 1\{X_k < Y_k\}}_{U_1}+\frac1{n^2}\underbrace{ \sum_{i<j} 1\{X_i < Y_j\}+1\{X_j < Y_i\}}_{U_2}
$$

Obviously, each term in $U_2$ is symmetric in $i,j$. I'm not sure what to do with $U_1$, so I'll ignore it for now. Redefine:
$$
U' := \frac1{n^2-n} \sum_{i<j} \big[1\{X_j < Y_i\}+1\{X_i < Y_j\}\big]=\frac1{n^2-n} \sum_{i<j} g(i,j)
$$

and again $\mathbb{E}(U')=\mathbb{E}(C)$. Next, if look at $U'$ as a function of $(X_1,\dots, X_n,Y_1,\dots,Y_n)$  it holds that:
$$|f(x_1,\dots,x_k,\dots,y_1,\dots,y_n)-f(x_1,\dots,x'_k,\dots,y_1,\dots,y_n)|\leq \frac{4\cdot(n-1)}{n\cdot(n-1)}=\frac 4 n$$

So using bounded differences inequality (see [Corollary 2.2 here](http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~mjwain/stat210b/Chap2_TailBounds_Jan22_2015.pdf) ) we finally get
$$\mathbb{P}(|U'-\mathbb E(U')| \geq \epsilon) \leq 2\cdot e^{\frac{-n \epsilon^2} 8} $$

Makes sense? how can I incorporate the diagonal indicators?

Comment: Mirrored from [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/245437/probability-of-random-variable-being-lesser-than-the-other)

Comment: You have to be much more precise and much more careful when phrasing a question.   Are $X$ and $Y$  identically distributed? What do those samples have to do with your question?

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu As the body of the question states, we do not know anything about the distributions of $X$ and $Y$. We do know, however, that he samples are drawn from these distributions.

Comment: What is then the info you know?   You want to estimate the probability of $C$ in terms  of  what  known quantities?

Comment: I'm trying to use Hoeffding-like concentration bounds to determine the sample size $n$ needed in order to be far no more than $\epsilon$ with probability at least $1-\delta$